# How use a preload script on electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron

I am currently doing the following:

```
//main.js

let window = new BrowserWindow (
    title: 'app',
    webPreferences: {
        preload: './preload.js'
    },
)

//preload.js 

window.teste = "hello"

//renderer.js

console.log(window.teste)
```

but I always get undefined, as if everything that was done inside the preload (requires and etc), had no global scope or could not be accessed in any way

Comment: what is renderer.js? where are you loading it?

Comment: renderer.js is just the js file that i use in my html file

Comment: to load it i'm just using <script src="./renderer.js"><script>

Comment: your code doesn't say where you're loading index.html

Answer (score 1):

The preload script runs in it's own context as does the application code, thus the `window` available for the preload script is not the same as the `window` in the renderer context. This is a security feature, more details can be found from [Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation).

Electron's `contextBridge` can be used to expose objects from preload script to the renderer context. Here's an example:

```
// preload.js
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("teste", "hello");

//renderer.js

console.log(window.teste)
>>> "hello"
```